# Jknzd in inline asm, error with compilation

Tags: c, inline-assembly, icc, xeon-phi

I try to make inline asm in C code for MIC (Intel Xeon Phi). And I have a problem with instruction jknzd.

This is a fragment of my code:

```
   float *A = (float*)_mm_malloc(N * sizeof(float), 64);
   int32_t* Indx = (int32_t*)_mm_malloc(N * sizeof(int32_t), 64);

   __m512i idx = __cdecl _mm512_load_epi32(&Indx[i]);
   asm (
          "kxnor %%k1, %%k1\n\t"
          "1:" "vgatherpf0dps (%0, %1, 4){{%%k1}}\n\t"
          "jknzd 1b, %%k1"
          :   
          :"r"(A),"x"(idx)
          :"%r8d", "%k1"
   );
```

Compiler is icc-13.0.1, options: -mmic -lrt -O3.
When I try to compile, I get this message:

> /tmp/icc1XDD1vas_.s: Assembler messages:
>   /tmp/icc1XDD1vas_.s:237: Error: invalid char '{' beginning operand 1 `{rz-sae}'
>   /tmp/icc1XDD1vas_.s:250: Error: invalid char '{' beginning operand 1`{rn-sae}'
>   /tmp/icc1XDD1vas_.s:254: Error: invalid char '{' beginning operand 1 `{rn-sae}'
>   /tmp/icc1XDD1vas_.s:260: Error: invalid char '{' beginning operand 1`{rn-sae}'
>   /tmp/icc1XDD1vas_.s:263: Error: invalid char '{' beginning operand 1 `{rn-sae}'
>   /tmp/icc1XDD1vas_.s:264: Error: invalid char '{' beginning operand 1`{rn-sae}'
>   /tmp/icc1XDD1vas_.s:360: Error: invalid char '{' beginning operand 1 `{rz-sae}'
>   /tmp/icc1XDD1vas_.s:373: Error: invalid char '{' beginning operand 1`{rn-sae}'
>   /tmp/icc1XDD1vas_.s:375: Error: invalid char '{' beginning operand 1 `{rn-sae}'
>   /tmp/icc1XDD1vas_.s:378: Error: invalid char '{' beginning operand 1`{rn-sae}'
>   /tmp/icc1XDD1vas_.s:383: Error: invalid char '{' beginning operand 1 `{rn-sae}'
>   /tmp/icc1XDD1vas_.s:385: Error: invalid char '{' beginning operand 1`{rn-sae}'
>   /tmp/icc1XDD1vas_.s:398: Error: invalid char '{' beginning operand 1 `{rz-sae}'
>   /tmp/icc1XDD1vas_.s:402: Error: invalid char '{' beginning operand 1`{rn-sae}'
>   /tmp/icc1XDD1vas_.s:415: Error: invalid char '{' beginning operand 1 `{rn-sae}'
>   /tmp/icc1XDD1vas_.s:417: Error: invalid char '{' beginning operand 1`{rn-sae}'
>   /tmp/icc1XDD1vas_.s:421: Error: invalid char '{' beginning operand 1 `{rn-sae}'
>   /tmp/icc1XDD1vas_.s:422: Error: invalid char '{' beginning operand 1`{rn-sae}'

If there is a simple jump, like "jmp 1b" it's ok. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds like something is getting garbled?  It might be interesting to see what's actually in the output (ie /tmp/icc1XDD1vas_.s line 250).

Comment: Are you hoping to make a vgatherpf0dps loop? Have you tried the gather prefetch intrinsics?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [invalid 'asm': nested assembly dialect alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34327831/invalid-asm-nested-assembly-dialect-alternatives)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be quite what you are looking for, but you can test for non zero values in the mask register using intrinsics.

From this [thread](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/518204) on the Intel MIC forum you can see a solution like this:

```
if(!_mm512_kortestz(mask, mask)) // Returns true if at least one bit is 1
{}
```